# rename elements in a column of a data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

Using pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n':['d','a','b','c','c','a','d','b'], 'v':[1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1]})
```

How can I rename the elements in `df.n`, such that `a` changes to `x`, `b` to `y`, `c` to `w` and `d` to `z`, resulting in:

```
   n  v
0  z  1
1  x  2
2  y  1
3  w  2
  ...
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary of replacement values into the Series [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method:

```
In [11]: df['n'].replace({'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'w', 'd': 'z'})
Out[11]: 
0    z
1    x
2    y
3    w
4    w
5    x
6    z
7    y
Name: n, dtype: object

In [12]: df['n'] = df['n'].replace({'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'w', 'd': 'z'})
```

Comment: Hello, how can I do exactly this but creating a df column instead of a list?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the below one:

```
df['n'].replace(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'w', 'z'])
```

This will replace all the a with x, b with y, c with w, and d with z. Note: if you pass two lists they both must be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly Modified from above:

movies['price'].replace({"$":"low","$$":"moderate","$$$":"high","$$$$":"very high"},inplace=True)

"Use inplace =True " otherwise dataframe won't be updated.

Comment: This solution does not answer the question. In addition, @Andy Hayden's answer also provides an update of the DataFrame.